# JQuery Calculator doesn't show results

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem with this jQuery-based calculator.  It doesn't run at all. No errors in console. Please help me to fix it.

What I want is when I click calculate button, the result of the calculation will show at the result spans.

```
<div class="line14"><span class="line15">&nbsp;</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="line16">
        <form method="post" name="test">
            <ul>
                <li> <span class="line16-lft">How many links will you post a day?</span>
                    <div class="line16-rght">
                        <select class="cus hasCustomSelect" id="numlinks" style="width: 77px; position: relative; left: 55px; height: 22px; font-size: 16px;">
                            <option value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="10">10</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="15">15</option>
                            <option value="25">25</option>
                            <option value="35">35</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="customSelect cus" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 53px; display: inline-block;">15</span></span></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <li> <span class="line16-lft">Average money earned for each Link?</span>
                    <div class="line16-rght">
                        <select class="cus hasCustomSelect" id="linksum" style="width: 77px; position: relative; left: 55px; height: 22px; font-size: 16px;">
                            <option value="10">$10</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="20">$20</option>
                            <option value="25">$25</option>
                            <option value="30">$30</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="customSelect cus" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 53px; display: inline-block;">$20</span></span></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <li> <span class="line16-lft">How many days a week will you work?</span>
                    <div class="line16-rght">
                        <select class="cus hasCustomSelect" id="daysperweek" style="width: 77px; position: relative; left: 55px; height: 22px; font-size: 16px;">
                            <option value="1">1</option>
                            <option value="2">2</option>
                            <option value="3">3</option>
                            <option value="4">4</option>
                            <option selected="selected" value="5">5</option>
                            <option value="6">6</option>
                            <option value="7">7</option>
                        </select>
                        <span class="customSelect cus" style="display: inline-block;"><span class="customSelectInner" style="width: 53px; display: inline-block;">5</span></span></div>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                </li>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </ul>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="line18">
        <ul>
            <li>Daily Income: <span id="daily_result">$300</span></li>
            <li>Weekly Income: <span id="weekly_result">$1500</span></li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>Monthly Income: <span id="monthly_result">$6000</span></li>
            <li>Yearly Income: <span id="yearly_result">$78000</span></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <span>
                <button class="line17" id="calculate">Calculate</button>
                </span></div>






<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calculate').click(function () {

            $('#daily_result').innerHTML = "$" + ($('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val());
            $('#weekly_result').innerHTML = "$" + (1 * $('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val() * $('#daysperweek').val());
            $('#monthly_result').innerHTML ="$" + (4 * $('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val() * $('#daysperweek').val());
            $('#yearly_result').innerHTML ="$" + (52 * $('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val() * $('#daysperweek').val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are mixing jQuery syntax and vanilla Javascript syntax in the following part:

```
$('#daily_result').innerHTML = "$" + ($('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val());
```

`$('#daily_result')` is a jQuery object. If you'd like to access the underlying DOM element and its `innerHTML` property, you should do:

```
$('#daily_result')[0].innerHTML = "$" + ($('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val());
```

But the other -- and probably better -- option is to use the `html()` method of jQuery:

```
$('#daily_result').html("$" + ($('#numlinks').val() * $('#linksum').val()));
```